# Plot subplots of different hourly time series: plot daily average on each hourly subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataframe with hourly measurements of 6 different meteorological variables for a year. I have tried to create subplots that show both the houryly and the daily average for each meteorological data in the same subplot. However, I'm not getting any close.

With this I get the subplots for each variable:

```
sns.set(style = "white", palette = "Dark2")
yaxis_titles = ['Global Irradiance $(W/m^2)$', 'Precipitation (-)', 'Relative Humidity (%)', 'Ambient temperature (°C)', 'Wind speed (m/s)', 'Wind speed direction (°)']
axes = meteo.plot( figsize=(12, 20), subplots=True, sharex = True, title = yaxis_titles)
```

I've tried to do something like this which gives me  sort off what I wanted BUT since I'm creating a plot per loop, then I'm not sure how to make them share the x-axis so that it doesn't result verbose.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(meteo.columns), sharex=True, tight_layout=True)

for i in range(len(meteo.columns)):
    s = 611+i 
    ax = plt.subplot(s) # s= nrows, ncols, index
    meteo[meteo.columns[i]].plot(title = yaxis_titles[i], label = "Hourly")
    meteo[meteo.columns[i]].resample("D").mean().plot(title = yaxis_titles[i], ax= ax, label = "Daily average")
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

EDIT:

I've found a way to do it but it's not yet perfect as the legends show are not correct. I would actually prefer not to show them at all or just to be able to point out that the black "--" line is the daily average.

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

yaxis_titles = ['Global Irradiance $(W/m^2)$', 'Precipitation (-)', 'Relative Humidity (%)', 'Ambient temperature (°C)', 'Wind speed (m/s)', 'Wind speed direction (°)']

meteo_mean = meteocorrect.resample("D").mean()

hourly = meteo.plot(figsize=(12, 20), subplots=True, sharex = True, title = yaxis_titles, label = None)
daily = meteo_mean.plot(subplots = True, ax = hourly, color='black', style = "--", label = None);
black_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='black',
                          markersize=15, label='Daily Average')
plt.legend(handles=[black_line]);
```

It gives something like this:

[image]

The problem is that with the "black_line" I haven't managed to make it dashed and even if I set the legend = None in the subplots, they still appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close. The main issue I can see is that you're not directly utilizing the Axes object you created before the loop.

I would loop through those and your dataframe columns directly and always pass the Axes object to the dataframes's `plot` method.

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(meteo.columns), 1, sharex=True, tight_layout=True)

for ax, col, title in zip(axes.flat, meteo.columns, yaxis_title):
    meteo.loc[:, col].plot(title=title, label="Hourly", ax=ax)
    meteo.loc[:, col].resample("D").mean().plot(title=titles, ax=ax, label="Daily average")
```

Comment: YEEEEIH, Thank you so much! I was struggling a lot!!